# I have a Modal that has the checkboxes to add a product, How can I have them checked when I want to update the Modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

//Product component renders the Modal component when the product is clicked
//handelClick() will setState dispalyProductmodal to true

```
<h6 onClick={() => {this.handleClick(); }}> {product.name}</h6>
if (this.state.displayProductModal) {
  productModal = (
    <ProductModal
      product={product}
      modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
    />
  );
}
```

//Modal component has all the product choices
// Cart component also renders the Modal component (so, you can view it and update choices)
//the diagram shows the flow of the code https://ibb.co/1r17Stx

Comment: Where is diagram???? provide more parts of your code

Comment: I made it as a link, hope it works

Comment: Use React Context to store your product state https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.